# Why the size of an empty directory in Linux is 4KB?

Tags: linux

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I made an empty directory on /tmp with the mkdir command:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir foo
```

and then I checked it's size using ls:

```
ls -ldh foo
```

and the result shows that the size of the directory is 4KB, although it has nothing inside!

then I created an empty file with touch:

```
touch empty
```

and then I checked its size:

```
ls -l empty
```

the result shows that the empty file is of 0B, which differs from the empty directory.

I've read about some Q&A's saying that the 4KB is the metadata of the directory. But if it is the metadata, what kind of information is stored inside and why it is so huge, and why an empty file don't have such kind of metadata? If it is not the metadata, what does the 4KB mean?

Comment: More appropriate on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 4KB is the least manageable unit size on disks and memory. Modern file systems have logs that record operations to make it easier to recover from machine failures.

Comment: Great question (even though it's maybe in the wrong place). Would be nice to be able to migrate it to the appropriate site.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'm going to break this question down into 3 parts, 2 of which I can answer...

Part 1: why isn't an empty directory size 0?

Because it contains `.` and `..` so it's not really empty.

Part 2: Why is 4K the minimum?

Because that's the filesystem's *block size*. You can set it smaller when you create the filesystem, but there is overhead. The filesystem must remember a free-or-in-use flag for every block, so smaller blocks = more blocks = more overhead. (In the early days of ext2, the default block size was 1K. Disks were small enough that the space saved by not allocating a multiple of 4K for every file was more important than the space used for the free block map.)

Block sizes over 4K aren't possible because 4K is the *page size* (the smallest unit of virtual memory) on most processors, and Linux wasn't designed to deal with filesystem blocks bigger than memory pages.

Part 3: When you `ls -l` a regular file, you get the actual number of bytes used but when you `ls -ld` a directory, you get the number of bytes allocated. Why?

This part I don't know. For regular files, there is an allocation size you can view with `ls -s`, and the two sizes actually tell you different things. But on directories, the `-l` size is like a redundant copy of the `-s` size. Presumably the kernel *could* report a size that indicates how much of the 4K block is actually used, but it doesn't. I don't know why.

Comment: Part 3 is because it makes no sense whatsoever to allocate anything other than full blocks; the rest of the space can't be used by anything else, and it's already possible to know where the dirents end.

Answer (score 2):

The metadata a directory contains is a series of [directory entries](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Directory-Entries.html). It's not empty upon creation because two dirents are immediately created: one for that directory, called ".", and one for its parent directory, called "..".