# du -ahx shows 15Gb in folder but there are only 32M in files on it

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, centos, directory

I've been passing by a problem.

I got 1 folder inside /tmp called schemajs.

This folder is from a project in jenkins.

If you use the command du -ahx it shows like this

```
15G .
66M ./schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1517089398135/schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64
66M ./schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1517089398135
66M ./schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1517087611935/schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64
66M ./schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1517087611935
66M ./schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1517085797988/schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64
66M ./schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1517085797988
66M ./schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1517084059192/schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64
66M ./schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1517084059192
66M ./schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1517082197124/schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64
```

The dot has 15G although there aren't enough files in the folder to justify this among of space used.

With the command ls -lha it shows several files with 4.0k with the total of 32M.

if I used vim .. it show more than 7500 files.

What could be happening in this particular case?

Platform: centos 6.9

Comment: Can you add **'ls -alh'** output to the question?

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu, sure same result with ls -alh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[4KB is  the size of a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666642/why-the-size-of-an-empty-directory-in-linux-is-4kb#26666779) and from what I see of **du** output your **/tmp** directory is full of directories (named for instance schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-151708939813) . Inside those directories are the file occupying disk space. It is always the same file of 66 MB named 
*schemajs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64*